# How to create different classes by conditon?

Tags: c#

Good to see you.

I am trying to assign class by condition but Csharp won't let me do it.

Because the name is duplicated. But I wanna use "name" as instance's name to minimize code.

For example.
#I am using mobile so please understand wrongn typijg

```
Random rand = new Randome();

switch (rand.Next(1,3))
{
   case 1 :
     ClassA name = new ClassA();
     break;
   case 2 :
     ClassB name = new ClassB();
     break;
   case 3 :
     ClassC name = new ClassC();
     break;
}
```

I tried many thing but I don't know how.. can you guys please help me?

Comment: Will you need to reference `name` outside of each case?  If not, you can simply surround each case block with `{` and `}` curly-braces to create a new scope.  If *yes*, then all three classes must derive from a common base class or interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can create interface (or abstract class)

```
public interface IClassAbc
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class ClassA : IClassAbc { public string Id { get; set; } = "I am classA"; }

public class ClassB : IClassAbc { public string Id { get; set; } = "I am classB"; }

public class ClassC : IClassAbc { public string Id { get; set; } = "I am classC"; }
```

and use random classes like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    var classInstance = GetClassInstance();
    Console.WriteLine(classInstance.Id);
}

public static  IClassAbc GetClassInstance()
{
   Random rand = new Random();

    switch (rand.Next(1, 4))
    {
        case 1:
            return new ClassA();

        case 2:
            return new ClassB();

        case 3:
            return new ClassC();

    }
    return null;
}
```

But I think that to get the random classes is  useless. This code could be usefull in some cases for a framework:

```
static void Main()
{
    var classInstance = GetClassInstance("classB") as ClassB;
    Console.WriteLine (classInstance.Id);
    
}

public static IClassAbc GetClassInstance(string className)
{
    
    switch (className)
    {
        case "classA":
            return new ClassA();

        case "classB":
            return new ClassB();

        case "classC":
            return new ClassC();

    }
    return null;
}
```